# Any boundary conditions missing from this problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics, boundary-conditions

Recently I was solving some boundary value problems in Electrostatics. I stumbled upon a problem with an infinitely long cylinder (axis along the $z$-direction and radius $a$) with a plate inside it (centered at $z=0$). The plate is perpendicular to the axis of the cylinder and has the same radius as the cylinder. The plate is maintained at a constant potential $V_0$. And the surface of the cylinder is maintained at a potential $V(\varphi, z$). It is asked to find $\Phi(\rho,\varphi,z)$ inside the cylinder.

Since it is an infinitely long cylinder I've used eigenvalues of the form $e^{ikz}$ and $e^{-ikz}$ and put the boundary conditions accordingly. But I'm missing a Boundary condition. Also, I'm considering one of the modified Bessel functions $I_\nu (x)$ as the region of consideration is bounded to inside the cylinder. Can someone help me with this?

Edit :  $\Phi(\rho,\varphi,z)$ is the electrostatic potential. $\Phi(a,\varphi,z) = V(\varphi,z) $ and $V(\rho,\varphi,0) = V_0$ are the two Boundary conditions. Since $V(\varphi,z) $ is a general function, I think I'm missing one boundary condition

Comment: I don't think there is an additional BC. Can you give a solid argument why you think its missing ? It's been a while since I did BV problems and I might be missing some details

Comment: I've deleted a number of obsolete comments and/or responses to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using my own symbols, for readability and writability but it'll be clear what's what, I hope.

[image: Cylinder potential]

Steady state wave equation in cylindrical coordinates:

$$\nabla^2u(r,\varphi,z)=0$$

$$\frac1r \partial_r (ru_r)+\frac{1}{r^2}u_{\varphi 
\varphi}+u_{zz}=0$$
$$\frac1r u_r+u_{rr}+\frac{1}{r^2}u_{\varphi \varphi}+u_{zz}=0$$

The domain for $R$, $[0,+a]$, for $\Phi$, $[0,2\pi]$, for $Z$, $[-\infty,+\infty]$.

Boundary conditions as stated:

$$u(a,\varphi,z)=V(\varphi,z)$$

and:

$$u(r,\varphi,0) =V_0$$

Ansatz:
$$u(r,\varphi,z)=R(r)\Phi(\varphi)Z(z)$$
$$\frac1r ZR'+ZR''+\frac{1}{r^2}RZ\Phi''+RZ''=0$$
$$\frac{R'}{rR}+\frac{R''}{R}+\frac{\Phi''}{r^2\Phi}+\frac{Z''}{Z}=0$$
$$\frac{R'}{rR}+\frac{R''}{R}+\frac{\Phi''}{r^2\Phi}=\frac{Z''}{Z}=-k^2$$
$$Z''+k^2Z=0$$

---

$$Z''+k^2Z=0$$
has the solution:
$$Z(z)=A\sin kx +B\cos kx$$
The boundary condition $u(r,\varphi,0) =V_0$ is first transformed to $u(r,\varphi,0) =0$, so that the BC is rendered homogeneous:

$$R(r)\Phi(\varphi)Z(0)=0 \Rightarrow Z(0)=0$$
This implies that $B=0$ and:

$$Z(z)=A\sin kx$$

This does not imply any 'sense', that is both $z\geq 0$ and $z\leq 0$ are covered.

---

$$\frac{R'}{rR}+\frac{R''}{R}+\frac{\Phi''}{r^2\Phi}=-k^2$$
$$\frac{rR'}{R}+\frac{r^2R''}{R}+\frac{\Phi''}{\Phi}=-k^2r^2$$
$$\frac{rR'}{R}+\frac{r^2R''}{R}+k^2r^2=-\frac{\Phi''}{\Phi}=-m^2$$

---

$$\Phi''-m^2\Phi=0$$
has the solution:
$$\Phi(\varphi)=Ce^{m\varphi}+De^{-m\varphi}$$
However, **no boundary conditions** to resolve $C$ and $D$ have been provided.

---

$$\frac{rR'}{R}+\frac{r^2R''}{R}+k^2r^2=-m^2$$
$$r^2R''+rR'+(k^2r^2+m^2)R=0$$
Solution to this DE:
$$R(r)=c_1 J_{im}(kx)+c_2Y_{im}$$
Where $J$ is the Bessel function of the first kind and $Y$ is the Bessel function of the second kind.

And here's a 'hidden' BC you thought you didn't have. Note that for $r\to 0$ the Bessel function of the second kind $Y\to -\infty$, therefore, $c_2=0$ and:

$$R(r)=c_1 J_{im}(kx)$$

---

A second boundary condition would stem from:

$$u(a,\varphi,z)=V(\varphi,z)-V_0$$
$$R(a)\Phi(\varphi)Z(z)=V(\varphi,z)-V_0$$
But I don't see the use of the latter equation, unless (implausibly) $\Phi(\varphi)=1$ and $Z(z)=1$.

---

In general, a second order PDE in three independent variables, after separation of variables, yields three second order ODEs, each ODE requiring two boundary conditions (BCs). The total number of BCs required is thus $6$.

Comment: So if I consider Bessel functions I'm assuming k to be real. That'll give me Z(z) as e^kz and e^-kz(exponentials). The problem with this is if I don't assume $\Phi(\rho,\varphi,z)$ tends to 0 as z tends to + and - infinity and keep them as such. I'll have two coefficients in front of them. How can I proceed further from there?

Comment: I might have to consider different exponentials on different halves of the cylinder (such that they go to 0). I'm trying to solve using this. Will let you know.

Comment: I put the boundary conditions on different halves of the cylinder and matched them at z = 0. I also used the property of $J_0(x)$ = 1 at x = 0 and $J_m(x)$ = 0 for all other m.

Comment: Following the above then $Z(z)=A\sin kz+B\cos kz$ (or with Euler, as a sum of complex exponentials). Trouble is that you **cannot** make $Z \to 0$ for $z \to \infty$ with those functions. So there's something quite wrong there...

Comment: Is $z = \pm \infty$ even really a boundary? Food for thought!

Comment: @Gert $\Phi(\rho,\varphi,\pm\infty)$ is determined by the boundary condition $\Phi(a,\varphi,z)=V(\varphi,z)$. So it's not a boundary in the sense that you can't set a boundary condition there.

Comment: @Gert About the use of exponentials in the solution. Can I consider the left and right half of the cylinder separately with $e^{-kz}$ and $e^{+kz}$ and match them to $V_0$ at z = 0?

Comment: No, you can't do that. I've made some edits to my answer and some more will be made today. Please watch. For $Z(z)$ I have a solution.

Comment: @Gert I recently got a clarification for the question. The potential on the surface of the cylinder  V($\varphi,z$) is to be broken into one part with $e^{-kz}$ and another with $e^{kz}$ so that it decays to 0 with z in different limits.

Comment: You're still missing BCs: you need $2$ per variable (because PDE is second order so each ODE needs $2$ integrations and thus $2$ BCs) making a total of $6$.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote!

Answer (score -1):

Correct me if I'm missing something @HeyDosa, but for the Laplace equation, $\nabla^2 \phi =0$, $\phi$ has the uniqueness property that if it is specified for the boundary of the region(volume) where you want to find it, then it is uniquely determined. Your region of interest is (in cylindrical coordinates), $S = [0,a]\times [0,2\pi]\times [-\infty,0] \cup  [0,a]\times [0,2\pi]\times [0,\infty]$.

Its boundary is simply given by
$$\partial S =  \{(a,\phi,z) \cup (\rho,\phi,0) | z \in \mathbb{R}, \phi \in [0,2\pi], \rho \in [0,a]\}$$ (pardon my sloppy notation, but I hope you get the idea.)
The boundary conditions $\phi(a,\phi,z)=V(\phi,z)$ takes care of the first half of $\partial S$ and $\phi(\rho,\phi,0) =V_0$ takes care of the second half. With these two, the whole boundary is taken care of and therefore the solution must be unique (so mathematically no other degree of freedom is left to be fixed by an additional BC).

Comment: Thank you for this. I am able to follow your argument. the given B.C seems to be sufficient. But I'm not able to actually solve this. Any help in this is appreciated.

Comment: I think what you need to solve is the simple case without the middle plate (that is a very standard problem and has solutions everywhere, check Jackson for an almost exhaustive treatment of such problems). Can you modify the given problem using superposition so that you basically have to solve for the case of 1) a cylinder with middle plate+walls at potential $V_0$ and 2)just a cylinder with boundary value $V(a,\phi,z)-V_0$? If you can do this the original problem is just a mixture of these two.

Comment: Superposition will only work if the boundary conditions for the plate (without the cylinder) and the cylinder(without the plate) match. I'm unable to do this

Comment: @HeyDosa. Consider just a cylinder with walls at $V(\phi,z)-V_0$ and $\phi(\rho,\phi,0)=0$. Find the solution to this, call it $\phi_1(\rho,\phi,z)$. Now take the solution $\phi_2 = \phi_1 + V_0$. Note how this satisfies the boundary condition of the original problem. By uniqueness theorem, this is the only solution. So just solve for the first part.

Comment: *I am able to follow your argument. the given B.C seems to be sufficient.* No, they aren't AT ALL. Most BC's are missing, which is why this can't be solved.

Comment: @Gert please mention one such BC that is missing and which boundary does it correspond to ? As I said its been a while an I've grown a bit rusty in this.

Comment: @Lelouch Please read my answer. There are two BCs missing for what I call $\Phi(\varphi)$ and one for $Z(z)$. One needs two BCs for $Z(z)$, 2 for $\Phi(\varphi)$ and 2 for $R(r)$...

Comment: @Gert, correct me if I am wrong, but what you're saying is missing looks more like constraint equations to pin down the values of the coefficients connecting linearly independent solutions of the DE. A boundary condition can be simultaneously used to fix multiple such constants: For eg. Fourier decomposing a given function $V(\theta)$ determines both the coefficients of $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$.

Comment: I've deleted a number of inappropriate comments and/or responses to them.